# Spring + Kafka: Transactions slow

Tags: performance, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

Just started using Spring Kafka (2.1.4.RELEASE) and Kafka (1.0.0) but when I added transactions, the processing speed was reduced a lot.

Code:

```
spring.kafka.consumer.max-poll-records=10
spring.kafka.consumer.specific.avro.reader=true
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id=${application.name}
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.isolation.level=read_committed
spring.kafka.consumer.key-deserializer=io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer=io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
```

And in Java I added:

```java
@Bean
ProducerFactory<Object, Object> producerFactory(KafkaProperties properties) {
    DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<Object, Object> factory = new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(properties.buildProducerProperties());
    factory.setTransactionIdPrefix(properties.getProducer().getTransactionIdPrefix());
    return factory;
}

@Bean
KafkaTemplate<Object, Object> kafkaTemplate(ProducerFactory<Object, Object> factory) {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(factory, true);
}

@Bean("kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> listenerContainerFactory(Environment env, ConsumerFactory<Object, Object> consumerFactory, KafkaTransactionManager<Object, Object> transactionManager) {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setAutoStartup(true);
    factory.setConcurrency(1);
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setGroupId(env.getRequiredProperty("spring.kafka.consumer.group-id"));
    return factory;
}
```

When I removed the `setTransactionManager(transactionManager)` statement, the speed increased by a huge amount. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kafka transactions are quite expensive - especially if you commit each send.

See [Transactions in Apache Kafka](https://www.confluent.io/blog/transactions-apache-kafka/).

Scroll down to "How transactions perform, and how to tune them".

> As we can see the overhead is independent of the number of messages written as part of a transaction. So the key to having higher throughput is to include a larger number of messages per transaction.

With Spring for Apache Kafka you can do multiple sends in the same transaction using the `executeInTransaction` method. Or by using Spring transaction management with a `KafkaTransactionManager` and performing multiple sends within a `@Transactional` method.

**EDIT**

I didn't notice the listener container; I presume you are consuming a message, performing some transformation and sending to another topic.  So in that case, you can't "send multiple messages in a transaction" since the container manages the transaction and, by default, commits after each delivery.

Increasing the concurrency won't affect the transaction semantics; in your case, (with concurrency 10), the partitions are distributed across 10 threads. Each thread runs a separate transaction.

You can speed it up further by setting `batchListener` to `true` on the container factory.

In that case, your `@KafkaListener` gets a `List<ConsumerRecord>` (or `List<Foo>`if you are using conversion); you can iterate over the list and process each record and send it with the template (don't use the `executeInTransaction` since there is already a transaction, started by the container thread). Then, when the batch is complete, the container will commit the transaction.

You can control the batch size with the kafka `max.poll.records` consuer property.

Comment: I see. I tried to change it to batch mode, polled 100 records at once and concurrency 10. This made it a lot faster, but how will the transactions work then? Is it exactly once or? If it fails after e.g. 5 records, where is the transaction wrapped? Around the 100 read, 10 concurrent or?

Comment: See the edit to my answer; I didn't notice you were using a transactional consumer; things are a bit different in that case.